# My laptop turns on again automatically after hibernation

Tags: debian, hibernate

So basically after I hibernate my laptop (debian 11), it won't go fully into hibernation mode first of all (I know this because my keyboard lights never turn off),and after a few seconds with a blank screen, it would always return to the session window, where I have to login and start again.

Any ideas about what could be happening?

Comment: Update the machine BIOS (firmware) and then update the Power Management driver.

Comment: You might want to confirm whether you are actually having problem with hibernation or suspend / hybrid-sleep first.

Comment: I can suspend my laptop without issues, the problem comes with hibernation @TomYan